# node.js and three.js as module; document no defined THREE.WebGLRenderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, express, three.js

I'm trying to use app to run a few functions I made from another .js file that defines those functions to allow me to draw objects on a canvas.

```
    app.get('/visualization.html', function(req, res) {

    //Set up scene and camera
    width = 1980;
    height = 1020;

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0,-40,160);
    camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0.3,2,2));

    //Set up renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    res.send(visualization.drawMultipleSunsAndPlanets(3, 4, 8, 4))
    res.send(visualization.keyboardListener())
    res.send(visualization.animate())
});
```

This is the snippet of code from app.js where I call a specific set of functions from visualization.js. (I'm trying to define the canvas and the renderer straight from the app...but I'm fairly certain I'm doing this wrong.

The error that I get when I try running app.js:

```
    $ node app.js
Listening on port 3000
THREE.WebGLRenderer 59dev
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at new THREE.WebGLRenderer (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules
\three\three.js:18671:70)
    at c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\app.js:80:17
    at callbacks (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\lib\r
outer\index.js:164:37)
    at param (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\lib\route
r\index.js:138:11)
    at pass (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\lib\router
\index.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\expres
s\lib\router\index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\l
ib\router\index.js:33:10)
    at next (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\node_modul
es\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
    at resume (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\node_mod
ules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:65:7)
    at SendStream.error (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\expres
s\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:80:37)
```

I have no idea what this undefined/missing documents is in THREE.WebGLRenderer is. If someone could help me, that would help me a lot.

Thank you,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

three.js is supposed to be used on client (that is, in browser), not on server. Node.js just doesn't have needed APIs. To do that just add `<script>` tag to your html file with three.js related code and serve it with `static()` middleware. Remember also to include `three.js` source and expose it to browser. If you want to save node.js goodies, like `require()` in browser, you can also try [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

Comment: I have a separate file called visualizer.html where I run the entire thing off just an html file, like you suggested. I was just wondering if that is the only possible option, since I have the remainder of my app running on app.js and I'd really like to be able to easily pass in parameters into the drawing functions. :(